# Store is not loading in Android Lollipop

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

My app isn't able to load the store in android lollipop version but it's working fine in older versions of android.

It doesn't work in lollipop until I require the store in **app.js**

```
requires:['StoreA','StoreB']
```

Is there any library that can fix an issue like this, such as in chrome 43?

If I require more than 200 stores initially, it might affect the performance of the application.

Comment: Are you using Sencha Touch 2? Why Ext JS tag then?

Comment: Is your issue with chrome 43?  Are you using sencha touch 2.4.2?  That version resolved many lollipop chrome issues

Comment: @James thanks for your response. No i am using 2.2.1. At this time i should not update my library. Is there is any fix for this ?.

Comment: @RED.Skull red you saved my life nearly literally, please post an answer and I will upvote it!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside view initialize function

```
var YourStore= Ext.getStore('YourStore').load();
     count =YourStore.getCount();
    console.log("count no"+count);
     if(count == 0){
          YourStore.load();
       }
```